# Configuration of gitlab-ci.yml file for maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to run 3 different jobs for 3 testNG suits on pipeline with in an order. with this configuration each job runs all tests , actually this configuration doesn’t take this suits from this file, it runs what pom.xml has, it has these 3 suits.

gitlab-ci.yml

build:
stage: build
script:
- mvn compile

stages:

- test1
- test2
- test3

ui-test-qa3-1:
stage: test1
script:
- ls
- mvn test -fn -DsuiteXMLFile="testQA3v2.2.xml"

tags:
- ui-test

ui-test-qa3-2:
stage: test2
script:
- ls
- mvn test -fn -DsuiteXMLFile="testQA3v2.2_1.xml"
needs:
- ui-test-qa3-1

tags:
- ui-test

ui-test-qa3-3:
stage: test3
script:
- ls
- mvn test -fn -DsuiteXMLFile="testQA3v2.2_2.xml"
needs:
- ui-test-qa3-2
tags:
- ui-test

and pom.xml build

install

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testQA3v2.2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                           <suiteXmlFile>testQA3v2.2_1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                              <suiteXmlFile>testQA3v2.2_2.xml</suiteXmlFile>

                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>


            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I tried to run without suite config. in pom.xml but than it runs all tests in the project.
I want to run job1 with suite1 and than job2 for suite2  then job3 suite3